# JSON accessing and showing in web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to show the JSON information on the web browser just to make sure I can access it.

The JSON is in the format

```
[
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:06.567000",
    "sensor_value": 9.7827
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:16.613000",
    "sensor_value": 9.80362
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:26.660000",
    "sensor_value": 9.80722
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:36.600000",
    "sensor_value": 9.77777
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:46.643000",
    "sensor_value": 9.79755
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:56.580000",
    "sensor_value": 9.91404
  }
]
```

I'm using the following html to test and show the objects as a 'ul'

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.getJSON('CLEVERTITLE.json',function(data){
            console.log('success');
            $.each(data,function(index,data){
                console.log("entered each")
                $('ul').append('<li>'+data.ts+' ' 
                               +data.sensor_value+'</li>'); 
            });
        }).error(function(){
            console.log("ERROR")
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using node live-server from the directory to access the files via `localhost:8080`.

However, running this is only giving me one bullet with text "undefined undefined". I am hoping to show `2016-10-10T04:40:46.643000 9.7777` . If I could access the "`ts`" and "`sensor_value`" tags as well it may be useful in the future. I'm sorry if this is very basic.

###########

EDIT: Turns out the issue was the volume of data. I was trying to show over a million data points. When I reduced the amount to a more reasonable number this worked correctly. Thanks to everyone that answered.

Comment: Can you confirm that the HTML can access your json file?

Comment: You probably misrepresented the data in the question, otherwise you wouldn't get any output at all

Comment: I'd guess your data is actually something like `{data: [{---}, {---}, {---}]}`, which would explain the single iteration with `undefined, undefined` for a result.

Comment: @zippydippy The data does have square brackets instead of the curly brackets .

Comment: @Momenator The html file doesn't return errors and outputs "success" and "entered each"

Comment: We're running around in circles here. Why don't you just do a `console.log(data)` of the data you get back from the JSON request to see what you're actually dealing with? Or just request the JSON file directly from the browser URL.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen okay I feel stupid. I ran this with console.log(data) which shows an array ob objects and then I saw the "entered each" start ramping up in numbers in the console. (Is there a way to upload an image?) anyways the main issue was the amount of data points are taking forever to load. if I lower the amount of data points the output worked as expected.

Comment: @zippydippy I think one file I was attempting to change was as you said [ { "data" : [{...}, {...}] } ] I changed that when i was trying to troubleshoot. I since changed it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. The outer structure should not be an object (`{}`), but an array (`[]`). An object contains a set of key/value pairs, while an array contains a list of values.

Correct as follows:

```
[
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:06.567000",
    "sensor_value": 9.7827
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:16.613000",
    "sensor_value": 9.80362
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:26.660000",
    "sensor_value": 9.80722
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:36.600000",
    "sensor_value": 9.77777
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:46.643000",
    "sensor_value": 9.79755
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:56.580000",
    "sensor_value": 9.91404
  }
]
```

Comment: sorry I just took a few of the values the actual file has square brackets on the outside [ ]. I just made a mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON File should be like this:

```
 [
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:06.567000",
    "sensor_value": 9.7827
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:16.613000",
    "sensor_value": 9.80362
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:26.660000",
    "sensor_value": 9.80722
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:36.600000",
    "sensor_value": 9.77777
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:46.643000",
    "sensor_value": 9.79755
  },
  {
    "ts": "2016-10-10T04:40:56.580000",
    "sensor_value": 9.91404
  }
]
```

Also add `<!DOCTYPE html>` before your `<html>` tag or else It would give the following warning in your browser console.

```
HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>".
```

Comment: How is that different from what's in the question?